# OpenCv VideoCapture Error in Linux - Setting property #0 is not supported

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, webcam, v4l2

I want to open webcam in c++ using Opencv in Linux OS.

```
int main()
{
    VideoCapture video(0);

    // ..
}
```

But there is small problem:

> VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: setting property #0 is not supported

I am only sure that webcam works. Because cheese works.

Thanks.

Comment: we don't look at pictures of problems. code is text... you can trivially paste the text into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter in this context is the camera index and the index `0` in Windows is either the first available camera or the one which is **not** plugged via USB (not exactly sure).

In Linux on the other hand, you just remove the parameter since it works by default on any available camera.

`VideoCapture video();` should work. And you can find more information in the [**Documentation**](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#gsc.tab=0).